# How to change properties of UILabels that are stored inside an NSMutable array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I know similar questions have been asked but I think I have tried their solutions.

Here is my code:

```
   NSMutableArray *sls;
   for (int c=1;c<6;c++){
      for (int r=1;r<6;r++){
         UILabel *s = [[UILabel alloc] init];
         s.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentCenter;
         s.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
         s.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
         s.layer.borderColor= [[UIColor cyanColor]CGColor];
         s.layer.borderWidth= 2.5;
         s.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",5*(5*(r-1) + c)];
         [s sizeToFit];
         [s setFrame:CGRectMake(c*45-20,r*45,s.frame.size.width+8,21)];
         [_map addSubview:s];
         [sls addObject:s];
      }
   }
   UILabel *t= [sls objectAtIndex:3];
   CGPoint c = t.center;
   c.y -= 10;
   t.center = c;
   t.text= @"T";
   t.backgroundColor= [UIColor yellowColor];
   t.layer.borderColor= [[UIColor magentaColor]CGColor];
   t.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-35*piO180);
```

All the labels are added to the array and are displayed just fine on my _map view but none of the edits I try to make, to UILabel at index 3, are done.

Why can't I change the UILabel at index 3 in any way that I try?  Thanks, Carmen

Comment: Because you never actually create the array.  All the bits you think you're putting there are falling into the bit bucket.

Comment: Hint:  Look at the value of `t` you get from the array.  It will be `nil` because `sls` is `nil`.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I did not initialize the array properly but haven't found the answer yet :) thanks

Comment: Hint: `sls = [NSMutableArray array];`.

Comment: Aha!,  NSMutableArray *sls= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  Thanks, I am learning!!  Surprised there were no warnings as simple as array never used or initialized, oh well, many thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you're using ARC and you like typing more characters that will work as well.

Comment: (Note that NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray and so supports all the methods of NSArray, including `array`.)